# Python environment when not deactivated

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtual-environment

After working in a Python environment I have forgotten to deactivate before moving on to other programmes. Does this cause problems. Do I return and deactivate?

I have observed that other programmes I have been using since moving on and failing to deactivate the environment I was working in seemed to work as they should.

Comment: If you did not do anything to your Python packages you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Note: it may depend on the type of virtual environment and operating system, but usually it doesn't matter. Virtual environments are very *virtual*: they adjust environmental variables, so that interpreter, modules, and libraries are loaded from a specific place.

And all of that is done just on the actual shell, so changes on rest of the system: in fact we often use different environments in parallel, in different shell/terminals/consoles.

And please note that one project may have different virtual environments, maybe to use some parts (production of documentation) or to test new versions of python and or modules, so there should be no problems on using the wrong environment on a project: often you get errors about wrong modules. But also we should be careful: bugs and "new formats" may ruin existing data.

Note: there may be exceptions and special cases. E.g. you may put specific activation procedures which break common assumptions.